# How to delete an XML element according to value of one of its children?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an xml element looking something like this:

```
<Description>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <SubDescription>
        <subID>4501</subID>
    </SubDescription>
    <SubDescription>
        <subID>4502</subID>
    </SubDescription>
</Description>
```

How can I delete the entire "Description" element according to the value of its "ID" child?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following xpath to select Description nodes that contain an ID node with value 1234:

```
//Description[./ID[text()='1234']]
```

So to remove the node, you can do:

```
doc.xpath("//Description[./ID[text()='1234']]").remove
```

Example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = %q{
<root>
    <Description>
        <ID>2222</ID>
        <SubDescription>
        <subID>4501</subID>
        </SubDescription>
        <SubDescription>
        <subID>4502</subID>
        </SubDescription>
    </Description>
    <Description>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <SubDescription>
        <subID>4501</subID>
        </SubDescription>
        <SubDescription>
        <subID>4502</subID>
        </SubDescription>
    </Description>
</root>
}
doc = Nokogiri::XML(str)
doc.xpath("//Description[./ID[text()='1234']]").remove
puts doc
#=> <root>
#=> <Description>
#=>     <ID>2222</ID>
#=>     <SubDescription>
#=>     <subID>4501</subID>
#=>     </SubDescription>
#=>     <SubDescription>
#=>     <subID>4502</subID>
#=>     </SubDescription>
#=> </Description>
#=></root>
```

As you can see, the desired description node is removed.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: Note: your XPath can be made much simpler (if perhaps more "magical" seeming): `//Description[ID='1234']`

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz, I did not know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use the solution by @JustinKo, albeit with the simpler XPath:

```
doc.xpath("//Description[ID='1234']").remove
```

However, if crafting XPath isn't your idea of fun, and writing Ruby is, you can lean on Ruby harder (if slightly less efficiently):

```
doc.css('ID').select{ |el| el.text=="1234" }.map(&:parent).each(&:remove)
```

That says:

- Find all the elements named `<ID>`
- But pare that down do just the ones whose text is `"1234"`
- Map this to be the `<Description>` nodes (the result of calling `.parent` on each)
- And then call `.remove` on each of those.

If you know that there's only ever going to be one match, you can make it simpler with:

```
doc.css('ID').find{ |el| el.text=="1234" }.parent.remove
```

Answer (score -3):

To find the ID do:

```
id = doc.xpath("//ID").text
```

where doc is the Nokogiri object created from loading the xml document

To check if the element id is what you want try:

```
if id == "1234"
```

From your xml file this should return true

Finally to remove the entire Description use:

```
doc.xpath("//Description").remove
```

What you're looking for is this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))    #create Nokogiri object from "test.xml"
id = doc.xpath("//ID").text    #this will be a string with the id
doc.xpath("//Description").remove if id == "1234"    #returns true with your xml document and remove the entire Description element."
```

Comment: -1 `xpath` is going to return a NodeSet. If there are multiple `<ID>` nodes in the document, all will be returned, and `text` is going to return content from all of them, which will keep `id == "1234"` from matching. Similarly, `xpath("//Description").remove` will remove all `<Description>` nodes from the document.